# Using an old Windows 7 on a new laptop (and upgrading to Win 10)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, license, license-key

I am currently looking to buy a new laptop on a somewhat tight budget. In order to get a bit better parts I have the option of buying it without a Windows license. I need Windows however and after some thinking I remembered that I have an old PC collecting dust which should have a retail version of Windows 7. Now I've long forgotten where the key is or even if I had a key (it might have been a volume license thing from work) so I have a few questions...

1. How can I check what type of license I have and whether it can be transferred to a new PC?
2. If I can use the old license, how can I see the activation key?
3. I've read that even now (about 2 years later) one can still upgrade to Windows 10 for free? How is the best way to do this? I mean is it better to upgrade on the old PC and then reinstall on the new one, or should I install Win 7 on the new laptop and then upgrade?

I hope I've managed to ask my questions clearly enough as I don't think I understand Microsoft's licensing policy well.

Thank you!

Comment: Boot up the PC and see if you can use the `slmgr.vbs` script to find the key in use. it'll also tell you the license type. Additionally, you should be able to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro if your current version is 7 Pro or 7 Ultimate. Enterprise doesn't look like it's eligible for Windows 10 upgrade...

Comment: The Windows 10 upgrade offer expired 2 years ago.  You can either purchase a Windows 10 license or continue to migrate your Windows 7 license to your new machine.

Comment: @Kinnectus It is Win 7 Pro, so this is good... I will try this and see what happens: https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/

Comment: @Ramhound there still seems to be the capability to activate Windows 10 if you use the media creation tool and a legitimate Windows 7 key. I successfully upgraded a Window 7 Home Premium to Windows 10 only a couple of months ago. It's still activated so it seems Microsoft have left this (one might say) "backdoor" open...

Comment: @Kinnectus What type of key did you use? I found out what my key is and it turns out it is a MAK one. I also have one OEM license on my current PC, so this may also be an option...

Comment: It was an OEM on a Samsung laptop - used the sticker on the bottom...